# Ive been getting a error: "in function main: undefined reference to Fraction::Fraction()"

Tags: c++, reference, compiler-errors, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fraction
{

private:
  //variables to store numerator and denominator
  int num;
  int denom;

public:
  Fraction();
  Fraction(int num): num(num) {}
  Fraction(int num, int denom): num(num), denom(denom) {}

  int get_numerator() const {return num;}
  int get_denominator() const {return denom;}
};

istream &operator>> (istream &input, Fraction &f)
{
  int n, d;
  char slash;
  input >> n;
  input >> slash;
  input >> d;

  f = Fraction(n, d);
  return input;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &output, const Fraction &frac)
{
  return output << frac.get_numerator() << "/" << frac.get_denominator();
}

int main()
{
  Fraction frac(1,2);
  Fraction frac2;

  cout << frac << endl;

  cin >> frac2;
  cout << frac2 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I am trying to create a fraction data type.
The code should allow the user to input a fraction using the overloaded ">>" operator but it does not work as i get an error:
in function 'main' : undefined reference to Fraction::Fraction()

Ive tried the code without the overloaded input operator and it works fine.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `Fraction();` -> `Fraction() {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler is asking for definition of following function(a default constructor):-

```
 Fraction();
```

which you have not provided.

Comment: Thank you. All i needed was to add curly brackets like this: Fraction(){}